Program upgrade "breaks" the other programs calling it
Given the max_invoke_stack_height limiting the maximum number of CPIs to just 4 and the A->B->C->D chain of nested CPIs, what if the implementation of the instruction D changes (via a bytecode upgrade) from not making any CPI calls - to now invoking an instruction E from another program?
Naturally, any calls from C to D will start failing, because the CPI calling D must now specify (in the accounts field of the instruction) the E-containing program account it now touches.
However, even if the C-containing program would adapt and pass the extra account address, the tx calling the instruction A would still fail, as this would now generate a CPI call stack that's "too deep".
Are there any conventions/best practices that Solana Developers follow to minimize similar situations?

The best convention, which isn't perfect, is to avoid breaking changes to instructions, and instead to use new instructions if the interface changes. That way, downstream users have a chance to try out the new flow before publishing their new program
